# MacBook Optimal Disk Formatting

Tags: disk-format

What's the optimal formatting for a MacBook disk?

My disk seems to be formatted as a LVG (Logical Volume Group) and it seems *super* slow...

Answer (score 4):

Optimal is what it's formatted as when you get the machine.
GUID/HFS+

LVG/Core Storage is necessary if you ever enabled FileVault. [Some updates to Yosemite also seem to have triggered that conversion too]

Try [Blackmagic Disk Speed Test](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/blackmagic-disk-speed-test/id425264550?mt=12) to see what speeds it's actually achieving.

Comment: Blackmagic Disk Speed Test is basically showing me 70MB/s read and write, doesn't look good....

Comment: that's not terrible for a HD, especially if it's only a 5200 rpm unit. Most of my HDs here are only pulling between 70 & 90MB/s, the fast one at 145, my SSD at 260